# How to write factory functions for subclasses?

Tags: python

Suppose there is a class `A` and a factory function `make_A`

```py
class A():
...


def make_A(*args, **kwars):
# returns an object of type A
```

both defined in `some_package`.

Suppose also that I want to expand the functionality of `A`, by subclassing it,
without overriding the constructor:

```py
from some_package import A, make_A

class B(A):

    def extra_method(self, ...):
    # adds extra functionality
```

What I also need is to write a new factory function `make_B` for subclass `B`.

The solution I have found so far is

```py
def make_B(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    same as make_A except that it returns an object of type B
    """
    out = make_A(*args, **kwargs)
    out.__class__ = B
    return out
```

This seems to work, but I am a bit worried about directly modifying the
`__class__` attribute, as it feels to me like a hack. I am also worried about
unexpected side-effects this modification may have. Is this the recommended
solution or is there a "cleaner" pattern to achieve the same result?

Comment: Maybe it's possible for you to add a constructor to `B` that consumes an object `A`, then just `out = B(make_A(*args, **kwargs))`?

Comment: Seems from the code you shared that the `B.__init__` function is inherited from `A` and `B` does not override it, so you could simply modify the function `make` to return initialization parameters and not the instance itself?

Comment: @MiquelEscobar. Since make_A is provided by another package and its implementation may change in the future, I don't think that this is the best option

Comment: Then probably the best solution would be what @AlexeyLarionov proposes.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov @MiquelEscobar. Writing such a constructor seems a bit drastic for my purposes, especially since `A` is may be quite complex and I am worried that I may be miss some details, especially if the implementation of A changes.

Comment: Are you allowed to add a constructor to `B` or not?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I am allowed to add a constructor to `B` but I would not like to override `__init__`, since I would like to keep the interface of `B` as close to `A` as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I finally found something not verbose yet still working. For this you need to replace inheritance with composition, this will allow to consume an object `A` by doing `self.a = ...`.

To mimic the methods of `A` you can use `__getattr__` overload to delegate those methods (and fields) to `self.a`

The next snippet works for me

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, val):
      self.val = val
   def method(self):
      print(f"A={self.val}")

def make_A():
   return A(42)

class B:
    def __init__(self, *args, consume_A = None, **kwargs):
        if consume_A is None:
            self.a = A(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.a = consume_A

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.a, name)

    def my_extension(self):
        print(f"B={self.val * 100}")

def make_B(*args, **kwargs):
    return B(consume_A=make_A(*args, **kwargs))

b = make_B()
b.method() # A=42
b.my_extension() # B=4200
```

What makes this approach superior to yours is that modifying `__class__` is probably not harmless. On the other hand `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are specifically provided as the mechanisms to resolve attributes search in an object. For more details, see [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@satishgoda/python-attribute-access-using-getattr-and-getattribute-6401f7425ce6).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you also add a short comment as to how this method is better than modifying the `__class__` attribute of the returned object in `make_B`?

Comment: Because I'm not sure if modifying `__class__` is harmless. On the other hand `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are specifically provided ([tutorial](https://medium.com/@satishgoda/python-attribute-access-using-getattr-and-getattribute-6401f7425ce6)) as the mechanisms to resolve attributes search in an object.

Comment: Thank you, again. I took the liberty of editing your answer to include your last comment as well. If you don't agree, feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your original factory function more general by accepting a class as parameter: remember, everything is an object in Python, even classes.

```py
def make(class_type, *args, **kwargs):
    return class_type(*args, **kwargs)


a = make(A)
b = make(B)
```

Since B has the same parameters as A, you don't need to make an A and then turn it into B: B inherits from A, so it "*is* an A" and will have the same functionality, plus the extra method that you added.

Comment: I think it's required to call `make_A`, which comes from an external library

Comment: This assumes that the arguments of the `make_A` function are directly passed to the class constructor. What I have in mind is a more general factory function that, for example may read some data from one or more files and then construct the object.

Comment: You could make a `make_A()` function that uses `make()` under the hood, and put all shared functionality that should be run in both `make_A` and `make_B` in a separate function that you call inside them.